Cryptic Acrostic 8: Instructions Unclear
This is an acrostic puzzle which uses cryptic clues. If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, you can click the associated link.
A complete answer should give the quote, author and source, as well as solutions and explanations of the cryptic clues.
As always, I've created an interactive version that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!
An accessible version for the visually impaired can be found here.


That was tough, but satisfying! I solved enough to find the quote, which helped me to backsolve most of the clues, but I needed help from jucifer and oAlt to complete this.
The quote is:

 Reading biology texts reminds me what it is like for other people reading math: a string of words and symbols that looks like normal language yet transmits no new information to my brain as it parses them.

 — Matt Parker, Humble Pi: A Comedy of Maths Errors

The clues:
A.  Maria making a face, IMO, could be this? (3 2 3 4)

 MAN IN THE MOON (Maria making a face) = reverse wordplay, because "man in the moon" could be M (man) in I.O (moon).

B.  A very short length of time, in the memory of Mr. Lee (8)

 ANGSTROM (a very short length) = T (time) in ANG'S .ROM (memory of director Ang Lee)

C.  Musician with drum - they'll get under your skin (6 6)

 TATTOO ARTIST = double definition based on two meanings of tattoo: A military parade that features many drum rolls and skin ornaments inked beneath the skin.

D.  Duty to train revolutionary on juicifer's classification (8)

 TAXONOMY (classification) = TAX (duty) + (t)O ("to" train, i.e. trailing letter) + NO< ("on" revolutionary) + MY (jucifer's)

E.  Ref spoke as a potential result of going all out? (7 3 5)

 PLAYING FOR KEEPS (result of going all in; meaning business) = reverse wordplay, because FOR KEEPS is an anagram ("playing") of REF SPOKE.

F.  I'm all about the bases! (2 6)

 AL KALINE = double def, kinda: Alkaline is all about the bases and not the acids; Al Kaline was a famous baseball player and as a good hitter, he ran the bases a lot, so he was also all about the bases.

G.  Language Italians hear, primarily (7)

 ROMANSH (language) = ROMANS (Italians) + H(ear)

H.  Frat bro activities that may make you nut? (3 6)

 KEG STANDS (frat bro activities) = reverse wordplay, I guess, because a keg is a TUN and if that makes a frat-boy-like handstand, you get NUT.

I.  Inside the ring, boxing? That'll knock you out cold (5)

 ETHER (will knock you out cold; an anesthetic) = hidden in ("boxing") (Insid)E THE R(ing).

J.  Return, angry about fight (6)

 REWARD (return) = WAR (fight) in RE.D (angry)

K.  Maybe her OS produces a bug? (8)

 HORSEFLY (bug) = reverse wordplay, because HORSE could be an anagram ("fly") of HER OS.

L.  Instructions for E-sport? (8 7)

 ULTIMATE FRISBEE (sport) = reverse wordplay, because "ultimate (frisbe)E" could be an instruction to get E. (Not super sold on just "ultimate" here, and not, for example, "ultimate in", though.)

M.  Lowers harvests (4)

 MOWS = double def of grimacing and of cutting crops.

N.  Man about to join a union got feet tangled up at end of bridge and fell over (10)

 BRIDEGROOM (man about to join a union) = BRID(GE>EG) ("bridge with feet tangled up) + reversal of MOOR (fell over)

O.  American sitcom whose lead character is a man named Mike Ng, perhaps? (4 3 8)

 LAST MAN STANDING (American sitcom whose lead character is Mike) = reverse wordplay, because "last man standing" could cryptically mean NG.

P.  As with Elizabeth, Charles ultimately cross and old (9)

 ERSTWHILE (old) = ER (Elizabeth Regina) + (charle)S (ultimately) + T (a cross) with WHILE (as). A with B could mean either AB or BA.

Q.  Maybe the mascot of the University of Miami has taken over within government! You can't prove that it hasn't happened! (11)

 POSSIBILITY (you can't prove that it hasn't happened) = reversal of IBIS'S (mascot of University of Miami has) in PO.LITY (maybe government).

R.  Color that might make you senile? (6)

 INDIGO (color) = reverse wordplay, because SENILE could NIL in SE.E and therefore "in dig (see, understand), o (zero, nil)". I couldn't solve this even with the answer already there, but oAlt could. Thanks!


great work! I actually intended {ybjref = sebjaf = zbjf} for L but your explanation works too. my justification for F was that {ur jnf n tbbq uvggre, fb ur ena gur onfrf n ybg (hasbeghangryl ur jnf na bhgsvryqre naq abg n hgvyvgl vasvryqre, juvpu jbhyq'ir znqr guvatf zber pbairavrag)}. other than that, no complaints! just waiting on that last clue :)

@MOehm R is rot13(n erirefr pelcgvp vaqrrq: va frr (= qvt = haqrefgnaq), avy (= B = mreb).)

@oAlt: Oh, so another indirect reverse wordplay. I tried something similar with the literal constituents, but neither doig nor diog mean senile. Thanks!

@juicifer: Ah, thanks. Your explanation for M fits better of course, but I didn't know that meaning of mow and always thought that lower would be spelled lour in that meaning, but MW tells me it's less common. I guess F is pretty well known, but your detailed explanations are lost to this baseball ignorant, I'm afraid.

(I hope I don't sound too negative, because I enjoyed the puzzle. And the interactive online version, which I used, is super.)
